# Counter in javafx interface

Tags: java, javafx

I have got a progress bar in javafx code which shows the time remain for a task in the java application. My code for the bar is the following:

```
task = taskCreator(saveSpeedInt);
pbar.progressProperty().unbind();
pbar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
new Thread(task).start();
```

Where taskCreator:

```
Task<?> taskCreator(int seconds) {
    return new Task<Object>() {

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                updateProgress(i + 1, seconds);

            }
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

I want to create a label in my interface that do the same as progress bar but with illustrating the time (in inverse way). How can I do so? The time of the task is stored in saveSpeedInt.

**EDIT:** What I want finally is to initialize the counter (to start the counter from the beginning) when an button event is happening, how can I achieve so in your example using a button?

Comment: Could you explain more what you really expect from your bounty because James_D is one of the biggest java FX expert in SO so I'm afraid that you will hardly get a much better answer than this one unless what you want are couple of links to the javadoc or something like that and if so, you should have asked him directly, you would have saved 50 points.

Comment: His answer is correct, I just want to find a way to stop and initialize the timer using a button.

Comment: It should be another question then

Comment: You could also use the ProgressIndicator.  Look here:http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/progress.htm

Comment: Is there a probability that I can use the same timer of the progress bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() ->
    String.format("Seconds remaining:  %.0f", saveSpeedInt * (1 - task.getProgress())),
    task.progressProperty()));
```

or

```
label.textProperty().bind(
    task.progressProperty()
    .multiply(-1)
    .add(1)
    .multiply(saveSpeedInt)
    .asString("Seconds remaining: %.0f"));
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Counter extends Application {

    private final int saveSpeedInt = 60 ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ProgressBar pbar = new ProgressBar();
        Label label = new Label();

        Button start = new Button("Start");

        start.setOnAction(e -> {
            Task<?> task = taskCreator(saveSpeedInt);
            pbar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

            new Thread(task).start();

            label.textProperty().bind(
                    task.progressProperty()
                    .multiply(-1)
                    .add(1)
                    .multiply(saveSpeedInt)
                    .asString("Seconds remaining: %.0f"));

//          label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() ->
//              String.format("Seconds remaining:  %.0f", saveSpeedInt * (1 - task.getProgress())),
//              task.progressProperty()));
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10, start, label, pbar);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 120);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();





    }

    private Task<Void> taskCreator(int seconds) {
        return new Task<Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {

                updateProgress(0, seconds);

                for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    updateProgress(i + 1, seconds);

                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: What's the cause of the exception?

Comment: Its the bind function!! This is the line of the error!

Comment: No, I mean, what is the cause of the exception in the stack trace?

Comment: It is java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '0'

Comment: That solved the problem. My only issue that instead of having the saveSpeedInt remaining seconds I got less (instead of 20 I ve got 15)

Comment: Furthremore can I initialize the counter when an event take place?

Comment: @JoseRamon Of course. Just put the code that creates the task and binds the label text and progress bar in the button's handler.